# Is there a way to make Braintree drop-in ui to use a local version of dropin.min.css instead of CDN?

Tags: css, braintree

I am using [livestyle](https://github.com/One-com/livestyle) to update css changes in real time in my dev setup. It tries to access 'rules' property of the link element, which is not accessible due to some CORS issue. My browser console gets flooded with console errors.

`livestyle-client.js:92 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'rules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules`

livestyle works fine with all the local CSS files.

> The error occurs at: 
>   https://github.com/One-com/livestyle/blob/a93729183fe070d285f58f6bb1256b216f51a1f5/livestyle-client.js#L92

Is there a way to make Braintree drop-in ui to use a local version instead of using the one from CDN?

Comment: I added <link rel="stylesheet" href="" id="braintree-dropin-stylesheet"> to my head tag, copied contents of dropin.min.css to a local stylesheet and imported that stylesheet to the component. This has solved this issue. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: But once i use `instance.teardown`, it removes this <link> element from the DOM. And on the next 'dropin.create', it starts using the CDN.